# use `strace` track `system("clear")` system call

Tags: assembly, system-calls, gnu-assembler

I want to clear terminal, and I found two solutions:

1. [How can I clear the screen without having to fill it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239143/how-can-i-clear-the-screen-without-having-to-fill-it)
2. [linux nasm assembly clear screen in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206629/linux-nasm-assembly-clear-screen-in-terminal)

I implemented `2` solution, it works. And BTW, What is the syntax `. - clear` of name, I can't found in [using as](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/).

```
.section .data

clear:
    .string "\033[H\033[2J"

.equ CLEAR_LEN,  . - clear
    

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
    movq $1, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $clear, %rsi
    movq $CLEAR_LEN, %rdx 
    syscall

    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

For `1` solution, I have a doubt. I use `Xshell` connect remote linux, rather than use `MSDOS`, so the size of window can changable. If we wanna know the size seems difficult. So I think this solution is unworkable.

In addition, I think we use `system("clear")` in `C`, so it probably works in assembly, and then I use `strace` track below c code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    system("clear");

    return 0;
}
```

And I found some strange `system calls`. Is it clear terminal?

```
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fadf89dc0c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fadf89dc0c0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0

...

rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], [CHLD], 8) = 0

...

rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fadf89dc0c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fadf89dc0c0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=640502, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

Comment: Try `.equ CLEAR_LEN, $-clear`.  In nasm, the current location is spelled `$` instead of GNU as' `.`.

Comment: The `rt_sigaction` and `rt_sigprocmask` calls are used by the `system` function to wait for the `clear` command to complete.  If you program with the libc, you can simply call the `system` function yourself.  Otherwise, it's a bit tedious to get right as you'll have to find the `clear` binary and then do a  `fork` + `exec` + `wait` to emulate the effect of `system`.

Comment: @fuz It sounds a little complicated. Have other solutions to clear terminal??

Comment: @fuz In Gas, `$-clear` is error. I can't found it in official documentation.

Comment: Again, for GNU as use `.-clear`, for nasm use `$-clear`.  The solution you have there is already correct, not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: If you wanted to know what `.-clear` means: `.` is a special symbol referring to the current location.  If you compute `. - clear` right after having laid out the string starting at label `clear`, this evaluates to the length of the string.

Comment: Solution (1) you linked is for DOS only btw, it will not be useful to you at all.

Comment: See [section 5.4](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dot.html#Dot) of the GNU as manual.

Comment: Did you read the comments on the [linux nasm assembly clear screen in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13206629) Q&A you found?  It doesn't depend on screen resolution, only on the terminal being VT-100 compatible.  (i.e. `TERM=` some variation of xterm or vt100.)  It moves the cursor to top-left, and then clears it.  That's vastly simpler than fork+exec of a whole process which will ultimately just do the same thing, writing a fixed string to stdout.

Comment: Also, if you didn't use `strace -f`, it won't trace into the `clear` process, so you'll just the parent process (your program) doing fork and wait, and signal stuff.  If you just want to see what `clear` does, `strace clear` in the shell, instead of writing a program that runs it.

Comment: Your question title is weird.  `system()` isn't a "system call", it's a library function that makes a *bunch* of system calls.  And the process it spawns will also make multiple system calls, although only its `write(1, "\33[H\33[2J\33[3J", 11)       = 11` is actually important.  It does query some terminal stuff about stderr first with `ioctl(2, TCGETS, ...)`  and checks terminfo.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry for the misunderstanding. Just like you said, I wanna asked question is `system()` lead to a bunch of system calls.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, I read the comments, but I don't know that what is the `VT-100`, and about something compatible.

Comment: @OnlyWick VT100 is the terminal on which the ANSI terminal standard is based.  If it works on the VT100, it'll work on any reasonably modern (post 1990-ish) terminal.

Comment: AT&T syntax is not fragmented, no idea what you mean or what you're talking about.  There's only one dialect of AT&T syntax, vs. Intel syntax having MASM vs. NASM and some others, with each having their own syntax for directives, too.  Almost all the assemblers that support AT&T syntax also support the same directives as GAS, so it's pretty uniform.  (e.g. clang's built-in assembler, and not much else.)

Comment: As far as what's new in x86-64, https://web.archive.org/web/20160609221003/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html is pretty good, covering the new architectural features in 64-bit mode.  PGU is good for the basics of memory, calling conventions, assembly in general, and how the pieces fit together (OS processes, ELF object files I think).